# How to install Django-nonrel (Django 1.9)?

Tags: django, mongodb

> I am trying to setup mongodb with django 1.9 using this link:
>   http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/setup.html
>
> if i install Django-nonrel using pip install
>   git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.5
>
> then it automatically install django 1.5 but we are using django
>   latest version in my project and also we can see this document Last updated on Feb 01, 2016. Can you please take look? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You literally can't.

From the [github page for django-norel](https://github.com/django-nonrel/django)

> This branch is 953 commits ahead, 7149 commits behind django:master.

The most recent change was 11 months ago, before 1.9 was finalised.

Also, don't. If you want to use MongoDB, there are plenty of better frameworks. Django's bread and butter is being a rock solid Object relational mapper for traditional relational databases.

Comment: Thanks Lego Stormtroopr