# Latest django-mongodb-engine

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I'm following the [guide](https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/setup.html) to setup django-mongodb.  But this line `pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.5` always reverts my django to 1.5.  Is there anyway that I can use lastest django?

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520252/how-to-install-django-nonrel-django-1-9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `django-nonrel`is a fork from the original Django project.

You can consider that as a different project.
`django-nonrel` was developed side by side with the original Django project until version `1.6`, **the last commit for nonrel is 2 years old**.

To sum it up, if you want to use `django-nonrel` it is not recommended and you are limited to latest Django version it supports - 1.6.

The `django-nonrel` project is dead - If you want to use a NoSQL I will recommend not using `Django`.
There is't any official support for that, and I did not find any on-going projects (third-party) that exist anymore.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.6
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest django-mongodb-engine is no longer operational. Using mongoengine alone will work only if your project does not use ANY contrib modules like, session, auth, user.

I recently came across another package called [djongo](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo). It is working fine on the latest version of Django.

Disclaimer: I have contributed to this package, but i am not trying to promote it anyway. I think it solves most of the Django MongoDB issues that have been around for ages and is extremely easy to use.